# I'm having trouble only inputting letters, not numbers

Tags: java, regex

For my project I need to input a first and last name with no numbers but I simply can't find anything online. If you could help, that would be terrific.

Also if you have the time, I need to flip the first and last name with a comma when the user inputs them.

```
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.io.IOException;

    public class PhoneListr {

public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    System.out.println ("Please enter your first name:");
    firstName = PhoneList ("");
    System.out.println ("Please enter your last name:");
    lastName = PhoneList ("");
    System.out.println ("Your full name is: " + lastName + "," + firstName);
}

public static String PhoneList (String input) throws IOException {
    boolean continueInput = false;

    while (continueInput == false) {

            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));
            input = bufferedReader.readLine();
            continueInput = true;

            if(input.matches("[a-zA-Z]+")) {
                continueInput = true;
                    }
                  else {
                 System.out.println ("Error, you may only use the alphabet");
                 continueInput = false;
        }
    }
    return input;
}
```

}

Comment: arent you getting any exception with above code ? :-O

Comment: Flip the first and last name with a comma ? I dont get what you mean ? #elaborate ?

Comment: When the user inputs their first and last name, I need to print out their first and last name again but with their last name first, a comma and then their first name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use [String.matches(regex)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29):

```
    if(input.matches("[a-zA-Z]+")) {
     System.out.println("your input contains no numerics");
        }
      else {
     System.out.println("only alphabets allowed");
}
```

the above regex checks a through z, or A through Z, inclusive (range).

Answer (score 1):

For this type of string matching you need to use Regular Expressions, or "RegEx"es. It is a very big topic to cover but [here's an introduction](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html). RegExes are tools used to test whether strings match certain criteria, and/or to pull certain patterns out of that string or replace certain parts that match those patterns with something else.

Here is an example using a RegEx to test whether your input contains a digit:

```
if(input.matches("\\d")) {
 // matched a digit, do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on OP problem and clarification here are few suggestions.

Chaitanya solution handles the *check for only alphabets* perfectly.

About the neglected areas of problem :

i would advice you to make two variable `firstName` and `lastName` inside the `main()`

```
String firstName;
String lastName;
```

Change retun type of method `phoneList()` to `String`

return the entered name `input` insted of `number` inside the method `phoneList` ( dont actually see why you are returning number)  and store it inside the `firstName` and `lastName`

```
System.out.println ("Please enter your first name:");
firstName = PhoneList (0);
System.out.println ("Please input your last name:");
lastNamr =PhoneList (0);
```

now to print it in the "comma format" use

```
  System.out.println("full name is: " +lastName+ "," +firstName);
```

As i read your program again , its a mess!!

About the method `phoneList()`

> 1. Use regex condition to set continueInput to true/flase and not exploit execptions.

P.s. I would appreciate "editing" to post , if any fellow member find any mistakes above, using a mobile, not sure about formatting etc. Thanks. :-) (y)

Comment: You my friend, truly are a life savior. Worked perfectly.

Comment: @user1718272 : u r wc. Thats for `SO` is for.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
if(input.matches("[^0-9]"))
{
System.out.println("Don't input numbers!");
continueInput = false;}
```

Can't understand what 2nd question asks. For answer what I get from your 2nd question is like this.
In main function change the code like this

```
String first_name = null;
String last_name = null;
System.out.println ("Please enter your first name:");
first_name = PhoneList();
System.out.println ("Please input your last name:");
second_name = PhoneList();
System.out.println (second_name+","+first_name);
```

then in PhoneList function last line should be changed to

```
return input;
```

Please check for [a link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29)! for more info

Answer (score -1):

You can add a check by passing the argument to method  [StringUtils.isNumeric](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.3/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#isNumeric%28java.lang.String%29)

This returns true if the String entered  is numeric

Comment: `isNumeric` returns true if the string contains only digits, what about the case when input is combination of alpha,numbers and spl. Chars. I think using `isAlpha` is a better choice. But rather than importing an api just for this is heavy. RegEx can be used as chaitanya points out in his answer.